# Potential energy of Spring and its oscillation frequency

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

Can the energy obtained from the relation between the frequency, spring constant and reduced mass of a spring be equated to the potential energy of the spring?

Comment: Why should it? Clearly, since the oscillation frequency is independent of $x$ and $E$ is not, there cannot be any connection...